# hive pyspark date comparison

Tags: hadoop, hive, pyspark

I am trying to translate a hiveQL query into pyspark.  I am filtering on dates and getting different results and I would like to know how to get the behaviour in pySpark to match that of Hive.  The hive query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(zip_cd) FROM table WHERE dt >= '2012-01-01';
```

In pySpark I am entering into the interpreter:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
import datetime as dt

hc = HiveContext(sc)
table_df = hc.table('table')
DateFrom = dt.datetime.strptime('2012-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
table_df.filter(psf.trim(table.dt) >= DateFrom).count()
```

I am getting similar, but not the same, results in the two counts.  Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code first creates `datetime` object from date `2012-01-01`. Then during filtering the object is replaced with it's string representation (`2012-01-01 00:00:00`) and dates are compared using lexicographically which filters out `2012-01-01`:

```
>>> '2012-01-01' >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
False
>>> '2012-01-02' >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
True
```

To achieve the same result as SQL just remove code with `strptime` and compare dates using strings.

Comment: Ahh I see.  Thank you!